# Ansible apt task that both upgrades packages and removes unused packages

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following task:

```
- name: Upgrade all packages (Debian family)
  become: true
  apt: 
    upgrade: safe 
    update_cache: yes
    autoremove: yes
```

It's a bit unclear to me if this will run both the upgrade and the autoremove.
I have tested the task and it doesn't yield in any error, but also I couldn't see if it tried both 'options'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible will not perform both actions in one step. In the example task from the question, the `autoremove: yes` option will be ignored.

1. `autoremove: yes` is only parsed in the [`install`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ba353b0f8fa5ddf43302c47acc67f8c30023c260/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py#L489) and [`remove`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ba353b0f8fa5ddf43302c47acc67f8c30023c260/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py#L637) methods (performed with `apt-get` command)
2. `upgrade: safe` [causes Ansible to run](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ba353b0f8fa5ddf43302c47acc67f8c30023c260/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py#L677) `aptitude` command (and it doesn't have the `--auto-remove` option at all (and on top of that it's not even considered in the `upgrade` method)